# Booting into UEFI shell with qemu

Tags: uefi, qemu

I've set up an environment in QEMU, but I'm having some troubles booting into the UEFI console. I'm running QEMU v 5.0.1 and am running Ubuntu 16.04 using edk2 for my UEFI environment with `MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc` as the platform for my OVMF build. I am using the following command for booting my QEMU system:

```
sudo qemu/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1G -enable-kvm \
    -machine q35,smm=on \
    -smp cores=4,sockets=1 \
    -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 \
    -kernel linux-stable/arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    -vga qxl \
    -display gtk,show-cursor=on \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=OVMF_CODE.fd \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=copy_OVMF_VARS.fd \
    -hda images/example.qcow2 --append "root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyS0" \
    -hdc qemu-img.img \
    -debugcon file:debug.log -global isa-debugcon.iobase=0x402 \
    -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:55555,server,nowait -device e1000,netdev=net0 \
    -netdev user,id=net0
```

After running, it goes straight into Ubuntu ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ToI.jpg)), but I've been trying to boot into the UEFI shell so I can view the memory map addresses, but I'm unable to boot into this before Ubuntu boots. I've tried entering <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and every <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> key while it's booting, but none work. I've tried running `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` but this returns `Cannot indicate to EFI to boot into setup mode: No such file or directory`. I'm unsure what else to try. Is  there a qemu option I can pass when initially booting to go into the EFI shell instead of booting into Ubuntu?

Comment: Why `-kernel `?

Comment: I think `-kernel` is for providing the linux kernel image to boot into and run. Without it, I get an error screen that there's no image.

Comment: I can get into UEFI settings by pressing Esc with `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -bios /usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF.fd`. After that I can boot UEFI shell that is built into OVMF in the `Boot Manager` menu. If I want a different version, I can just create a raw image with an ESP (with the help of e.g. `losetup -P`; even just `mkfs.fat` the image directly should be fine) and put the shell executable as `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`. Then just specify it to a `-drive file=`. No idea what error you are getting, since normally qemu can be started without a drive/image anyway.

Comment: Actually `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -bios /usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF.fd -nodefaults -display gtk -vga std` gets me directly to the builtin UEFI shell.

Comment: FYI: I can enter UEFI environment by pressing `ESC` key when I see `[Bds] BdsWait ...` from the console at booting. But I am using `qemu-system-aach64` with firmware `QEMU_EFI.fd`.